# Point dispose error in using statement

Tags: point, using, idisposable, using-statement

**I need to dispose Point variable. Some point codes overload to my RAM.**

**Code**

```
 using (var result = new Point(0,0) )
 {
 //Codes
 }
```

**Error Message**

```
'Point': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable
```

Comment: wait for it to go out of scope or call gc collect but you should have to worry about that.  You can't put a using on something thats not disposable

Comment: Okay @johnny5 very thanks for answer. İ will try gc collect.

Comment: @johnny5 Thank you so much. It is worked. :)